# How to append data CollectionViewCell array to UIViewController array

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I add favorite button on `collectionviewcell` for saving favorite images on an another `UIViewController` class.
When I press on button, its image change to red image. I've created button action in `CollectionViewCell` Class, and I want to store "data" array value or current selected index values in "items" array of `UIViewController` Class according to cell indexpath when button is pressed.

And when I pressed again on this button it delete stored value of this indexpath from "items" array of `UIViewController` according to cell index path.
The main problem is that ViewController type variable is not create on collectionviewcell?
Actually I am trying to show favorite cell data in another CollectionView like in `UIViewController` Class.

Can anyone please tell me how I can do that?

[image]

*

```
import UIKit
class LiveCollectionView: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, DrapDropCollectionViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet var dragDropCollectionView: DragDropCollectionView!


    var objects : [Dictionary<String, String>] = [
        ["url" : "https://s3.amazonaws.com/kargopolov/BlueCafe.mp3", "image": "1.jpg"],
        ["url" : "https://s3.amazonaws.com/kargopolov/BlueCafe.mp3", "image": "2.jpg"],
        ["url" : "http://2016.downloadming1.com/bollywood%20mp3/Sanam%20Teri%20Kasam%20(2016)/02%20-%20Kheech%20Meri%20Photo%20-%20DownloadMing.SE.mp3", "image": "3.jpg"],
        ["url" : "http://2016.downloadming1.com/bollywood%20mp3/Sanam%20Teri%20Kasam%20(2016)/03%20-%20Bewajah%20-%20DownloadMing.SE.mp3", "image": "4.jpg"],
        ["url" : "http://2016.downloadming1.com/bollywood%20mp3/Sanam%20Teri%20Kasam%20(2016)/04%20-%20Tera%20Chehra%20-%20DownloadMing.SE.mp3", "image": "5.jpg"],
        ["url" : "http://2016.downloadming1.com/bollywood%20mp3/Sanam%20Teri%20Kasam%20(2016)/02%20-%20Kheech%20Meri%20Photo%20-%20DownloadMing.SE.mp3", "image": "6.jpg"],
        ["url" : "http://media.downloadming.se/TEMP/Loveshhuda%20(2015)/01%20-%20Mar%20Jaayen%20-%20DownloadMing.SE.mp3", "image": "5.jpg"],
        ["url" : "http://2016.downloadming1.com/bollywood%20mp3/Sanam%20Teri%20Kasam%20(2016)/01%20-%20Sanam%20Teri%20Kasam%20-%20DownloadMing.SE.mp3", "image": "7.jpg"]]

     override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        dragDropCollectionView.draggingDelegate = self
        dragDropCollectionView.enableDragging(true)
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return objects.count
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("collectionViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! LiveCollectionViewCell

        let object = objects[indexPath.row]
        cell.imageView.image = UIImage(named: object["image"]!)
        cell.data = object

        return cell
    }

    func dragDropCollectionViewDidMoveCellFromInitialIndexPath(initialIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toNewIndexPath newIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let colorToMove = objects[initialIndexPath.row]
        objects.removeAtIndex(initialIndexPath.row)
        objects.insert(colorToMove, atIndex: newIndexPath.row)
}

}
```

*

```
import UIKit
class LiveCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell{

    var showPlayButton = true

    var data : [String : String]!


    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var heartBt: UIButton!

    @IBAction func heartBt(sender: UIButton) {


        if showPlayButton {

            self.heartBt.setImage(UIImage(named: "rHeart"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            showPlayButton = false
            print(data)

        }
        else
        {
            self.heartBt.setImage(UIImage(named: "wHeart"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            showPlayButton = true

        }


    }

}
```

*

```
import UIKit

    class ViewController: UIViewController , UICollectionViewDelegate{

        var items : [Dictionary<String, String>]?

        let reuseIdentifier = "collectionViewCell"

        override func viewDidLoad(){

        }

        func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
        {
            return self.items!.count
        }

        func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CollectionViewCell
        {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

            var object = items![indexPath.row]


            cell.imageView.image = UIImage(named: object["image"]!)

            return cell
        }


        }
*
```

*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to create a class that will hold the URL and the state if it is liked or not.
Save an array of these kind of object in [Core Date](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/index.html)
, then when you open each viewController, load the core date items into an array that can be displayed. and when you make changes save the core data items to the core data database.